# Why can't I upload a JPEG image?

Tags: support, images

Upon trying to insert an image as part of a post, from a web source, an error occurs saying:

> format not supported

The image in question was a JPEG.

Are JPEGs no longer supported as an image format?

Comment: What image did you try? Could you post the URL?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - http://zoetrope.speakermouth.com/assets/2008/4/9/textmate_lisp2.jpg

Comment: @ldigas This isn't a bug: it's an issue with the image host. Your question was revised to reflect that: please do not roll it back again.

Comment: @MarkTrapp - What part of my question, now revised, differs from what I said in my original revision?

Comment: @ldigas This is a support issue, not a bug: marking things bugs when they aren't adds noise for SE developers. Additionally, `.jpg` isn't a file format, it's an extension.

Comment: @MarkTrapp - From my side, as a user, it's a bug. Also, I didn't say anywhere .jpg is a file format (my words were ".jpg ... image format" which is correct, if somewhat unprecise).

Comment: @ldigas I appreciate the fact that it looks like a bug to you; one of the perks of Stack Exchange is that it's [collaboratively edited](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#editing) to ensure sure questions and answers are as accurate as possible: your question was edited to reflect that it's not actually a bug, despite its appearance.

Comment: @MarkTrapp - Oh, I don't mind that part of the edit. Edit all you want, it's your site & definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this error was indicative of [a problem on Imgur's end a few weeks ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109857/failed-to-upload-image-format-not-supported-error-when-uploading-supported-form), I can't reproduce this now. This is a JPEG upload:

[image: This is a JPEG]

Things to check:

- **You might be uploading a file that has the JPEG file extension but not the `image/jpeg` mimetype.** Have you tried checking to make sure the file is actually a JPEG and not something else? If you're on a *nix-based system, you can check by using [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file).
- **You're using the "From the web" option with a URL from a site that doesn't allow Imgur to rip its images.** Try downloading the image yourself and uploading it manually.
- **You're experiencing a localized disruption of Imgur.** Try uploading the image again to see if it works.

---

#### Edit

While the "From the web" option didn't work, downloading it first and manually uploading it worked:

[image: Image problem]

Looks like it's a problem with the image host.